# Mule: JUnit test case to call a service which is in middle of the Mule flow

Tags: junit, mule, mule-studio, mule-el, junit-rule

I'm newbie for JUnit  test case. Please help me on this issue. I have 2 mule flows- first flow having MQ as inbound and it has datamapper to transformer the xml. With the first flow input, i'm calling second flow where we are calling the existing service ( SOAP/HTTP) call. Please  find my JUnit below. I'm able to get the success response. But my requirement 
1. I need to see the transformer response coming out from the Transformer.( Like how we see via logger component in our flow)
2.Need to override the url (HTTP) through JUnit ( in order to test the error scenario)

```
    public class Request_SuccessPath extends FunctionalTestCase {
    @Test
    public void BulkRequest () throws Exception {
        MuleClient client = muleContext.getClient();
        System.out.println("test");
        String payload = " <root>  <messageName>str1234</messageName><messageId>12345</messageId><DS>123</DS><</root>";
        MuleMessage reply = client.send ("vm://test",payload ,null);}
@Override
    protected String getConfigResources() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return "src/main/app/project.xml";}
```

i thought the following snippet will override the url.But it is not

```
          DefaultHttpClient client1 = new DefaultHttpClient();  
    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://localhost:7800/service);
    assertNotNull(response);
```

3. How to take the control of the flow and see any response inbetween the flow.

Instead of WMQ, i have replaced VM as inbound end point for testing purposes.
4. Is there any chance like without replacing VM can we call directly with WMQ through JUnit TestCase. Kindly help me on this.
I'm using 3.4 version, not using maven as of now. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1) What do you mean by "see". Would it work logging it? inspecting it while debugging?

2) You should parametrize your endpoint with a variable, something like

and configure a property placeholder as explained here: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Using+Parameters+in+Your+Configuration+Files
Adding http.port, http.host and http.path variables to mule-app.properties

taking into account that you must set system-properties-mode="OVERRIDE" and then start your Mule server using bin/mule -M-Dhttp.host=your-host -M-Dhttp.port=your-port -M-Dhttp.path=your-path

3) Yes, WMQ has a Java API you can use to interact with it: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv6/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc%2Fuj41013_.htm , you will probably found hundreds of examples by googling about it.

Regards.

Comment: For the 4th question. http://javasourcecodeetc.blogspot.com/2009/08/putting-message-into-ibm-websphere-mq.html perfectly working.

Comment: @Ale-Thank you for your answer. I'm using config files to override the properties through JUnit as per the above link. But in my case, I'm using 3 flows.In 1st flow i'm having wmq where i put the message. In my second flow only i have http Outbound endpoint to call a web service. I'm able to override all the mq properties through config files, but not sure how to override http url via JUnit ( which is in 2nd flow).Kindly help me on this.